# Get the value of matched words from a list in a string

Tags: python

I have a list of words which I have to match in a string and get the matched value

```
metric = ["किलो","क्विंटल","kg","कीलो","कुंटल","ton","लिटर","किलोग्राम","quintal","KG","Quintal","किंटल","नग","कॅरेट","टन","liter","गुंठा","piece","dozen","caret","करेट","Kg","गुठा","kilo","dozens","lit","kwintal","कींटल","क्विंटल","kgs","tonnes","किवंटल","gm","tons","ml","किन्टल","gms","GM.","quintals","Tonne","litre"]
```

Example String:

```
80 रुपये किलो
```

I am getting Output as:

```
True or False
```

Expected Output

```
किलो
```

I tried using

Trial 1:

```
if any(word in 'some one long two phrase three' for word in list_):
   print(word)
```

But I am getting blank list as output

Trial 2:

```
first_match = (state for state in metric if state in text)
```

Here I get a generator object which cannot be printed

**I have to add the matched word into a dataframe**

Comment: "But I am getting blank list as output" Well, have you considered the possibility that none of the words are actually `in` the test sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the generator expression to [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to get the first value that matches. You will get a `StopIteration` error if it is not present. To avoid that, you can use the second argument to `next()` for the default value:

```
metric = ["किलो","क्विंटल","kg","कीलो","कुंटल","ton","लिटर","किलोग्राम","quintal","KG","Quintal","किंटल","नग","कॅरेट","टन","liter","गुंठा","piece","dozen","caret","करेट","Kg","गुठा","kilo","dozens","lit","kwintal","कींटल","क्विंटल","kgs","tonnes","किवंटल","gm","tons","ml","किन्टल","gms","GM.","quintals","Tonne","litre"]
s = '80 रुपये किलो'

next((state for state in metric if state in s), None)
# 'किलो'
```